# iTextSharp + xmlworker is not drawing well the width of columns in a table

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I have this html table:
[image: original html]

- This table has `table-layout: auto` and `width: 100%`
- None of the cells has a defined width
- **As you can see, the width of each column is automatically adjusted to the best fit, by the browser**

When I convert it to PDF with **xmlworker 5.5.3** (iTextSharp 5.5.3), I get this PDF:
[image: xmlworker html to pdf]

As you can see, **iTextSharp has decided very bad the widths for the columns** (compare it to how Chrome draws the table):
[image: Drawing wrong the widths of cells]

It is not efficient:

- Large columns are drawn too narrow (eg. 4th column)
- Short columns are drawn too wide

I tried other "html to pdf" tools and they do well with the width of the columns:

pupeeter (Chrome headless):
[image: pupeeter html to pdf]

wkhtmltopdf:
[image: wkhtmltopdf.exe html to pdf]

But what I like about iTextSharp is that I can use it directly on my web app hosted in Azure.

- puppeteer is made in node.js and my web app is made in C# / asp.net
- wkhtmltopdf needs to run in a B1 tier in Azure (expensive)

So... what am I doing wrong with **xmlworker**? or it is simply a bad library?

**UPDATE 1**

There is a puppeteer project for C# called "PuppeteerSharp". I'm trying now. Apparently it needs to be run along with browserless.io because Azure won't run Chrome on a web app (F1 at least...)

**UPDATE 2**

Not easy to run PuppeteerSharp in Azure.
For now, I deployed the GitHub project "url-to-pdf-api" in heroku, which uses Puppeteer, and I'm calling this from Azure. Not fast, not simple...

**UPDATE 3**

I tried updating from xmlworker 5.5.3 to xmlworker 5.5.13.2 and its even worse. It doesn't consider `style="width: 25%"` on `<td>` (which 5.5.3 does OK). What a terrible library

Comment: Have you tried using the most current itextsharp and xmlworker?

Comment: Can I get it with NuGet? @mkl

Comment: I would assume so; opening the NuGet manager in VS I see `iTextSharp`, `itextsharp.pdfa`, `itextsharp.xmlworker`, and `itextsharp.xtra` all available at version 5.5.13.2 (i.e. the second security update for the final version 5.5.13 of that project).

Comment: Hmm i think i will try first iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 (i'm using 5.5.3). Though they are both deprecated.  And then i will try iText7.pdfHTML.....

Comment: Beware, the API of iText 7 is completely overhauled, iText 5 to iText 7 is no simple drop-in update, you'll have to change your code considerably. Nonetheless, in most respects iText 7 is a clear improvement to iText 5.

Comment: When testing with iText 7, will there be a watermark because of the license?

Comment: As far as I know there is no watermark (I don't know for sure, though). But the use of iText 7 is mentioned in the producer properties.

Comment: I tried iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 (the latest) and it has the same problem calculating the column widths.

Comment: ...Even more: 5.5.13.2 has worser issues such as not considering fixed width of some cells